# Relation between transformers and the resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I have to create a circuit where i change 240V AC into 6kV DC. The amount of Amperes that comes out of it is 30mA. Following Ohms law, would that mean I need 20,000 Ohms resistance to be able to use the 6kV?

Comment: Won't 20,000 Ohms give you 300 mA, not 30  mA?

Comment: Definitely, off by a factor of 10. Also, 30mA at 6kV is 180 Watts. Don't know what you're proposing to use as your 200k "resistor," but if you connect a typical 1/4 Watt resistor of that value across the secondary, it'll go up in smoke quite quickly.